# execute function from address in elf file

Tags: linux, elf

I have a simple c file that prints a message in main and do nothing else
Compiled it using gcc to generate .out file.Use the elf parser to get the entry_address
of start function and using this addressas function pointer i am trying to execute the main function in c file but it is giving seg fault.

e.g

```
test.c
void main()
{
  print("something");
}
```

generated test.out elf file by gcc

and i get the following by doing nm test.out

```
0000000000601020 A _edata
0000000000601030 A _end
00000000004005e8 T _fini
00000000004003c8 T _init
0000000000400410 T _start
000000000040043c t call_gmon_start
0000000000601020 b completed.6531
0000000000601010 W data_start
0000000000601028 b dtor_idx.6533
00000000004004d0 t frame_dummy
00000000004004f4 T main
```

The start address is `0x0400410 T _start`.
Now i write another c code like below to execute the main function in test.c

```
execute.c
void main()
{

   typedef int func(void); 
   f = (func*)0x00400410;
   f();
 }
```

compiling excute.c by `gcc execute.c -o execute.out` is giving me segmentation fault on calling `f()`.

The desired output is to print `something`.

Is it possible to execute elf file function from address,where i am getting wrong.

Comment: did you try to 'nm' the latest elf for execute.c

Comment: When you build `execute.out`, it doesn't have any connection to `test.out` (as far as I can tell), so any addresses you get from `test.out` are meaningless in `execute.out`.

Comment: most code are relocatable -- the ELF loader may load them into different address on loadtime

Comment: XY problem. What are you trying to achieve?

Answer (score 4):

Your question demonstrates several fundamental mis-understandings. Let's take them one by one.

First, as hcs pointed out, `test.out` and `execute.out` have *nothing* to do with each other. When one is running, the other one is *not* loaded into your process space *at all*. Your expectation of being able to call a function in `test.out` from `execute.out` is not unlike counting money in my right front pant pocket (say you find a 25c coin there), then reaching into your own right front pant pocket and expecting to find that same 25c coin there.

Related to this, you are also expecting to even have the right pant pocket just because I have one (expecting to find `_start` at `0x00400410` in `execute.out` just because `_start` is at that address in `test.out`). You may in fact find `_start` at the same address, or you may not. Maybe you are wearing a kilt today, and it doesn't have a front right pant pocket at all.

Finally, think about the program execution. Who called your `main` routine? (That's right, `_start` did). Now you've arranged for your `main` to call `_start` again. What do you expect that do? It will call `main` again. And that will call `_start` again. This is called infinite recursion, and would cause your binary to crash with stack exaustion.

Note: the *actual* cause of the crash is different, and related to the fact that `_start` is not expecting to be called twice within the same process.